# Upload and manipulate xml and image file in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

This code return a TypeError as expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile
I don't know how to pass user data in the form of file and image to my code.py file for making changes to the original.

## views.py

```
def home(request):
new_image = None
file = None
form = ScanForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ScanForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        image = request.FILES['image']
        xml_file = request.FILES['xml_file']
        new_image = code.create(image, code.search(
            xml_file)[0], code.search(xml_file)[1])
        form.save()

        return render(request, 'app/home.html', {'form': form, 'new_image': new_image})
    else:
        form = ScanForm()
return render(request, 'app/home.html', {'form': form, 'new_image': new_image})
```

###### printing image and xml_file successfully prints out their names

## forms.py

```
class ScanForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Scan
    fields = '__all__'
```

## models.py

```
class Scan(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
xml_file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
processed_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-processed_at']

def __str__(self):
    return self.description
```

###### Here is the code for manipulation of image according to the data in the xml

## code.py

```
def search(path):
new = []
object_names = []
object_values = []

txt = Path(path).read_text()
txt.strip()
names = et.fromstring(txt).findall('object')
for i in names:
    object_names.append(i[0].text)
values = et.fromstring(txt).findall('object/bndbox')
for i in values:
    for j in i:
        object_values.append(int(j.text))

return object_names, object_values


def create(image, object_names, object_values):
img = cv.imread(image)
on = len(object_names)
ov = len(object_values)
for i in list(range(0, ov, on)):
    cv.rectangle(img, (object_values[i], object_values[i+1]),
                 (object_values[i+2], object_values[i+3]), (0, 0, 255), thickness=5)
return img
```

###### This code.py works fine if tested by passing data manually using local folder.

### Here is the Traceback:

[Traceback image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwDsF.png)

Comment: Can you share the whole traceback?

Comment: I have added the traceback image

Comment: Try to put the traceback as text next time :) Judging from it, `search` is accepting a path, but you are passing a file that is still in memory. I'm not sure what `search` and `create` are doing exactly so I can't give a suggestion, but you either have to save the file first and get the path, or change `search` to use the file in memory instead of a path

Comment: suppose I have an `image` in my `database` and I want to make changes to it using `pillow` but of only the image I `selected `from the database then how would i set the image path to `pillow`,  tried giving image.url and passing image but it doesn't worked for me and I don't know any other methods to do that.  Also I tried using http://localhost:80000/ + image url

Comment: Not totally sure, maybe update your tags and add `pillow` so people who have used pillow might give you ideas

Answer (score 1):

`pathlib.Path()` handles file paths, not memory objects. `request.FILES` are the data attached to the POST request. During your handling of a POST request, you can validate this data and decide to save it to the server disk.

If you would like your image processing to read the file from the server disk, you have to save the new model instance first. You can then access the file's path on disk through the `name` attribute of the model's ImageField, see [Using files in models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/#using-files-in-models).

If you want to handle the uploaded data *before* saving it to disk, you can read it as follows:

```
txt = request.FILES["xml_file"].read()
```

See [UploadedFile.read()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.read)